# How to filter docker container running by hour using shell script?

Tags: bash, docker, shell, docker-compose

I want to create a script that can filter docker running by hours.

Comment: Please post samples of your commands so that we could see where and how to take timings part from command's output.

Comment: What about containers that are running for months? Do you want them to show in the output?

Comment: My purpose is to filter docker status running 5 hours or more than 5 hour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are just concentrating on containers that are running for hours and not months, days or seconds, you can run:

```
docker ps -f status=running --format "{{.ID}}: {{.Names}} {{.RunningFor}}" | awk '/hours/ && $3 > 4 { print $0 }'
```

This formats the output of docker ps to print jus the ID, Name and running time for containers that are running. We then pipe the output to awk and check for any output with "hours". If we find the output, we check that the number of hours is greater that 4 (5 hours or more) and print the line.

Comment: Thank you for your sample. How if we want to filter only more than 5 hour?

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer